# Does script tags or jquery getScript double load when you call it when it's already loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just wanted to know how script tags and jquery getScript works. Lets say the script file is already loaded or in the process of loading. Then I dynamically insert a script tag or call getScript to load the same script file. Does it automatically know that the script is already there and not load it again, or does it load it again?

Comment: How would it *automatically know that the script is already there*?

Comment: This is one of the reasons that libraries like RequireJS are suggested for large applications. [Scripts will be run multiple times if loaded multiple times](http://plnkr.co/edit/X1ylHgCukzQ9V5ltTOOW?p=preview). It's also the reason that you'll see a lot of libraries use the "if window.myLibrary is not defined, then define it" strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Giving this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Script Check</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $.getScript("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Check the Network Log.
    </body>
</html>
```

We can see the network tab that it gets loaded again, as neither jQuery, nor the browser can guess if the URL is already loaded.

[image]

So jQuery is getting loaded twice and that's not a good sign. `JK`

Comment: Agreed, the best option is to manage it server side.  For dynamic pages, there are server side tools such as MS ToolkitScriptManager for aspx pages.

Comment: if I use getScript, how can I put a cache=true for it?

Comment: @omega why don't you refer the Ajax docs? Coz this is a shorthand and I'm travelling on bus so can't refer it.